# How to send data from site to browser?

Tags: ajax

I'd like to send data to browser from server (website).
For example on SO you receive notifications about new answers when answering a question.
Should I every n seconds send ajax queries to server, or there are better ways of doing this?
Is it possible to push data from server to browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term of art for what you're trying to do is "Comet", and the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) on the subject explains many approaches to implement it -- not "push", really, but as close as you can get with HTTP and friends;-).

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is pull-only, but you can keep a long-lived connection open in order to [allow for streaming](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming).